# Is there a way to create help in terminal like redis-cli?

Tags: shell, terminal, redis, redis-cli

I'm now using redis-cli to play with redis. And as I see redis-cli help me with arguments to command, so I'm easily understand order of arguments to type. I don't need to open documentation. You can see this on picture. 
[image]

I'm find this VERY helpful.
So is there a way to get this for normal Linux terminal? Maybe some plugins or something.
Thanks any answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many utilities that provide similar functionality like [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/).
You can download it using `apt-get install fish` 
Read the complete description [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-fish-shell-on-ubuntu).